# Type inheritance in declaration file

Tags: typescript

I'm declaring a "parent" COMPONENT type that other element types should satisfy. Below code works fine if I use it in a normal .ts or .tsx file (that is, it will show me that I can't use a type "hero" since it's not part of ELEMENT_TYPE).
However, in a declaration file, this just doesn't work.

How do I declare a generic type and then use that as a "mold" to fit other, more specific types, into, all in a declaration file?

```js
declare type ELEMENT_TYPE = "div" | "p" | "h1" | "button";

declare type COMPONENT = {
  type: ELEMENT_TYPE;
  children: (COMPONENT | string)[];
};

declare type Satisfies<T, U extends T> = U;

declare type HERO = Satisfies<
  COMPONENT,
  {
    type: "hero";
    children: (COMPONENT | string)[];
  }
>; // should throw error but does not in declaration (.d.ts) file
```

My tsconfig file looks as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it on https://www.typescriptlang.org/. I'm not sure how to write the code in a virtual .d.ts file instead of a normal .ts file.

Comment: My own tsconfig.json is the default from a next 14 (react-ts) project - I added it to my question

Comment: TSPlay does allow [filetype=.d.ts](https://tsplay.dev/mb1edN) but I still see the same issue. I don't know about react, is such knowledge needed? If so then you might want to tag the question as such. If not, you might want to include your tsconfig.json.  There are other web IDEs out there you can try which allow more than one file.  I don't know, I'm kind of stumped unless I can see it happen.

Comment: That's helpful to know about the filetype url flag. I added the tsconfig json to the question. I don't think that react is relevant, I only mentioned it to highlight which kind of tsconfig I had before just adding the whole json file to the question

Comment: *looks at tsconfig* so, can you turn off [`--skipLibCheck`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck)?

Comment: That's it. And now I feel lazy for not having discovered this one myself. Still wondering why Next puts this flag on true by default, I'm hoping nothing breaks later on. But so far, removing this flag shows the error and the rest of the code / ts functionality works fine without it at this point.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  I'll write the answer quickly, given that I can't seem to quickly find another question where the answer is "turn on skiplibcheck"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want TypeScript to check your declaration files, then you should disable [the `--skipLibCheck` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/skipLibCheck.html).